# Command works in cmd prompt but not in Powershell, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, windows, powershell, curl, cmd

So I've been tearing my hair out all day regarding this one. I have a curl command which I have working on a windows machine which pulls logs from Cloudflare, this works.

```
curl -sv -o logname.log.gz -X GET -H "Accept-encoding: gzip" -H "X-Auth-Email: myemail@email.com" -H "X-Auth-Key: 12345" "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/987654/logs/requests?start=1481509909&end=1481538709"
```

I'm trying to import this into powershell with the end goal of making the start and end time parameters different based on the current time, however I simply cannot get the command to run in powershell, I've tried various different tracks with this being the latest and most simple.

```
cmd.exe /c 'curl -sv -o logname.log.gz -X GET -H "Accept-encoding: gzip" -H "X-Auth-Email: myemail@email.com" -H "X-Auth-Key: 12345" "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/987654/logs/requests?start=1481509909&end=1481538709"'
```

Which gives me this error

```
{ [11971 bytes data]
* Failed writing body (0 != 11963)
* Failed writing data
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with api.cloudflare.com port 443
* schannel: clear security context handle
```

I already know that my unix timestamp is a bit off and plan on fixing that next but what I cannot understand is why the same command works through the command prompt and not through Powershell.

Would someone be able to help?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot use single-quotes for `cmd /C '...'` as `cmd` supports double-quotes only, like `cmd /C "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with parameters to native commands in PowerShell can be a minefield because you have to deal with quoting and special characters for both, sometimes nested.

It's probably safer to use `Start-Process` in PowerShell and give it an array of parameters:

```
Start-Process curl.exe -ArgumentList '-sv','-o','logname.log.gz','-X','GET','-H','Accept-encoding: gzip','-H','X-Auth-Email:','myemail@email.com','-H','X-Auth-Key:','12345','https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/987654/logs/requests?start=1481509909&end=1481538709'
```

But what you should realy do, is check out `Invoke-WebRequest` which will ultimately be much easier.

```
$body = @{
    start = 1481509909
    end = 1481538709
}

$headers = @{
    'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip'
    'X-Auth-Email' = 'myemail@email.com'
    'X-Auth-Key' = '12345'
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/987654/logs/requests' -OutFile logname.log.gz -Body $body -Headers $headers
```

Note this is not tested at all, but should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, so I can now get the request to run using the above however when it comes to access the log.gz file it tells me that the archive is in an unknown format or corrupted.

$body = @{
    start = 1481509909
    end = 1481538709
}

$headers = @{
    'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip'
    'X-Auth-Email' = 'myemail@email.com'
    'X-Auth-Key' = '12345'
    }

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/98765/logs/requests' -OutFile C:\logname.log.gz -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

Any ideas?